# Clustering algorithms for strings

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, pattern-matching, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I have to implement a module in which i need to group sentences(strings) having similar meaning into different clusters. I read about k-means , EM clustering etc. But the problem which i am facing is that these algorithms are explained with vector points on a graph. I am not getting how these algorithms can be implemented for a sentence(String) having similar meaning. Please suggest some appropriate ways.

For example ,
Lets consider a classroom scenario..
1) Teacher has ample knowledge.
2) Students understand what teacher teaches.
3) Teacher is sometimes punctual in class.
4) Teacher is audible in class.

Lets say we have these 4 sentences. Then looking at them we can say that sentence 1 and 2 are of similar meaning. But sentence 3 and 4 are neither related to each other nor to the first two. In this way i need to classify the sentences. So how can it be done?

Comment: This is a big question. I think that Google's 'Deep Learning' course on Udacity provides a nice and free introduction to text mining using `tensorflow` with python.

Comment: I don't think there's a single best answer to this question, so I'm voting to close it as too broad. That said - look at "Word to Vector" or "Word Embedding" models, which show a lot of promise in this area.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should make yourself familiar with the `bag of words` concept.
The basic idea ist to map each word in a sentence on the number of occurrences, e.g., for the sentences `hello world`, `hello tanay` would get mapped onto

```
Hello World Tanay
  1    1      0
  1    0      1
```

This allows you to use one of the standard approaches.

Also worthwhile would be having a look at `TF/DF` it is made to reweigh words in a `bag of words` representation, with their importance to distinguish the documents (or sentences in your case)

Secondly, you should look at LDA which was made specifically for clustering words to concepts. Nevertheless, it is made of a view concepts.

Most promising to me sounds like a combination of these approaches. Generate, `bags of words`, reweigh the `bag of words` using `TF/DF`, run `LDA` and augment the reweighed `bag of words` with the `LDA` concepts and then use a standard clustering algorithm.

Comment: Lets consider a classroom scenario..
1) Teacher has ample knowledge.
2) Students understand what teacher teaches.
3) Teacher is sometimes punctual in class.
4) Teacher is audible in class.

Lets say we have there 4 sentences. Then looking at them we can say that sentence 1 and 2 are of similar meaning. But sentence 3 and 4 are neither related to each other nor to the first two. In this way i need to classify the sentences. So how can it be done?

Comment: @TanayNarkhede: to improve your question, you should merge  this comment into it with an edit. Nevertheless, this example makes me doubt that it is possible. Because, even I as a human have a hard time to see the connection, as it is deeply hidden in the semantics of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Clustering **cannot** do this.

Because it looks for *stucture* in data, but you want to cluster by the abstract human concept of *meaning* that is hard to capture using statistics...

So you first need to solve the really hard task of **making the computer understand language** reliably. And not on a "best match" basis, but good enough to *quantify* similarities.

There are actualy some attempts in this direction, usually involving massive data and deep learning. They can do this on some toy examples such as "Paris - France + USA = ?" - sometimes. Google for IBM Watson and Google word2vec.

Good luck. You will need high-performance GPUs and Exabytes of training data.